# My separated javascript file does not show anything from ID, but works when on the body tag

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I'm trying to make some tabbed content on my HTML code with an external js file

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'idNo1')" id="defaultOpen">NO1</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'idNo2')">NO2</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'idNo3')">NO3</button>
</div>

<!--NO1Section-->
<section id="idNo1" class="tabcontent">
    <div>
        guheheheheh
    </div>
</section>

<!--NO2Section-->
<section id="idNo2" class="tabcontent">
    <div>
        mwehehehehehe
    </div>
</section>

<!--NO3Section-->
<section id="idNo3" class="tabcontent">
    <div>
        nyehehehehe
    </div>
</section>

<script src="vscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my external js :

```
    //tabcontent
    function openSection(evt, docName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i=0; i < tabcontent.length; i++)
            {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
    
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++)  
            {
                tablinks[i].className=tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
        
            document.getElementById(docName).style.display="block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active" ;
    }
        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

`document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();` works when I put it on body tag, but when I try separate it on external js, HTML doesn't show anything.

Comment: try using document.querySelectorAll instead of document.getElementsByClassName, it worked for me

Comment: If you have this <script src="vscript.js"></script> the vsscript.js has to be in the same folder where the html code is. Try to put a console log to see if openSection() is called for example.

Comment: There is no way the code works because `btnNo1` does not match `idNo1`

`onclick="openSection(event, 'idNo1')"`

Comment: Use the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) interface to add and remove classes rather than trying to do it on your own.

Comment: I'll try what you guys suggested later, thanks !